# Accessing "hidden" windows in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to set up an applescript which will handle a slightly-annoying VPN login process for me. I use Cisco AnyConnect, and every time I have to log back on, I have to hit connect, accept a certificate warning, enter my username, password, and select the right group, and accept ANOTHER certificate warning.

It's that second certificate warning I can't seem to get around.

Some digging indicates that the warning dialog is owned by a process named `vpndownloader`, but the odd thing is that **Applescript seems convinced that it has no windows and does not exist!**

I've been using Accessibility Inspector to get the window IDs and such to make this script work. For this particular dialog, it looks like this (accessibility inspector behind the actual dialog I'm attempting to control)

[image]

The strangeness comes in when I try to get the window's ID so I can do things with it.

```
tell application "System Events" to windows of process "vpndownloader"

{}
```

Blank. Okay, maybe there's something useful in the properties of the process?

```
tell application "System Events" to properties of process "vpndownloader"

{has scripting terminology:false
 bundle identifier:"com.yourcompany.vpndownloader"
 file:alias "Macintosh HD:opt:cisco:anyconnect:bin:vpndownloader.app:" of application "System Events"
 creator type:"????"
 subrole:missing value
 entire contents:{}
 selected:missing value
 application file:alias "Macintosh HD:opt:cisco:anyconnect:bin:vpndownloader.app:" of application "System Events"
 orientation:missing value
 role:"AXApplication"
 accepts high level events:true
 file type:"APPL"
 value:missing value
 position:missing value
 id:1212712
 displayed name:"vpndownloader"
 name:"vpndownloader"
 class:application process
 background only:true
 frontmost:false
 size:missing value
 visible:false
 Classic:false
 partition space used:0
 role description:"application"
 maximum value:missing value
 architecture:"i386"
 short name:"vpndownloader"
 focused:missing value
 minimum value:missing value
 help:missing value
 title:"vpndownloader"
 accepts remote events:false
 total partition size:0
 description:"application"
 accessibility description:missing value
 enabled:missing value
 unix id:9053}
```

(for giggles, note that Cisco didn't set their bundle identifier..)

No contents, no visible windows. Despite the dialog I've got up right in front of me.

So, on one hand it obviously has a window (accessibility inspector can see it), but AppleScript is convinced that it does not.

How do I programmatically locate and access this "phantom" dialog?

#### Things that didn't work:

```
tell application "vpndownloader" to windows

error "vpndownloader got an error: Can’t get every window." number -1728 from every window
```

Again the theme of this application being in a weird state between existence and nonexistence comes up

```
tell application "vpndownloader" to properties

error "vpndownloader got an error: Can’t get every property." number -1728 from every property
```

It has a menu bar, but no windows.

```
tell application "System Events" to get UI elements of process "vpndownloader"

{menu bar 1 of application process "vpndownloader" of application "System Events"}
```

Comment: Last 2 examples won't shouldn't work for anything; you need to use a process tell inside of a System Events app tell. What do you get  with `tell application "System Events" to get UI elements of process "vpndownloader"`?

Comment: @CRGreen It comes back with one menu bar and no windows when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just use keystrokes. For example when that window comes up you yourself can probably physically hit the "connect anyway" button by first pressing the "tab" key to change the focussed button and then press the "space bar" to select the focussed button.

NOTE: you may have to enable this functionality by enabling full keyboard access. Do this by going to system preferences->keyboard->shortcuts and checking "all controls" at the bottom of the window.

If you can then you can applescript it. The following will work as long as that window is frontmost when you issue the commands.

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.2
    keystroke space
end tell
```

Good luck.

Comment: That is an excellent idea and it's something I already tried, however Cisco saw fit to disable the tab key in those windows. In fact, that's the only reason I'm going about it this way :(

Comment: OK. Since you can't keystroke a solution then I suggest you download "UI Browser" from http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/. It's free to try. This is much better than Accessibility Inspector because it will show you the exact code to use to access that button. Good luck.

Comment: UI Browser can't actually see the process. If I set "follow focus" mode and then mouse over the dialog, I see that it's owned by `vpndownloader`, but it shows no contents in the main window.

Comment: Well, that's the problem then. It doesn't seem you can do it that way. One final suggestion. I released a program called MouseTools where you can perform physical mouse clicks programatically. So you can figure out the screen coordinates of the button using my tool, and then you know where to perform the mouse click (with my tool). Give it a try. Find it here: http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (I use anyconnect 3.1.06073).

https://gist.github.com/lotreal/ce43f4a85d8ae73781fa

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me. I'm using a slightly older version of the client, but as mentioned, for some reason the vpndownloader process is transparent to applescript. It cannot see the window to click on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an interesting workaround for this problem that doesn't involve scripting. It turns out the `vpndownloader` is entirely optional, and it apparently [only serves the purpose of updating the client when an update is pushed from the upstream server](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect31/administration/guide/anyconnectadmin31/ac09localpolicy.html)

A local policy XML can be defined to disable the process. This will cause breakage if an update is pushed (the connection will just abort), but it at least allows the login to be scripted.

On Mac/Linux systems, this file is located in `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/AnyConnectLocalPolicy.xml` - [I had to create one](https://gist.github.com/Karunamon/52d8c4cff0d06c2e5297) based on the schema file, `AnyConnectLocalPolicy.xsd` in the same folder. If it already exists, just edit the existing one.

The key line is `<BypassDownloader>`, which is set to `false` by default. Setting it to true means that the downloader is simply not run, meaning the second dialog I was trying to access simply never appears!